# Start/Stop NServiceBus service

Tags: msbuild, nservicebus

We are deploying several NServiceBus services on remote machine using msbuild.

On the first step we're syncing all our files using msbuild and uploading our self-executed archives (each archive contains needed dlls for one service) + cmd script to stop/start services to remote server. That works fine.

Then we execute the script. We have configured all needed delegation on IIS and executing the script with right permissions.

The script itself:

```
:doUpdateForService
net stop %SERVICE%
echo [*] Unpacking Service...
%workDir%\%SERVICE%.exe -d%TARGET_DIR% -s
echo     unpacking finished
net start %SERVICE%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto onerror
goto:eof
```

When we're doing it the first time (all services are stopped), it works just fine, but on the second run we cannot stop services at all. Even locally. It returns us something like this:

```
The service can not be controlled in the existing state.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `The service can not be controlled in the existing state.` is a very generic error, can you check if there is something more interesting in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: Where does the IIS come from?